# Plone and Asp.Net Integration

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, authentication, integration, plone

How to:

- Make an Asp.Net application to recognize a plone authenticated user (his/her id, roles and any other available data) and vice-versa?
- Show plone contents inside my asp.net application or show some application-specific data inside plone?
- Insert plone contents from inside an asp.net application?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of high level approaches:

Security:

- Put a web server in front of both Plone and the ASP.net application and use the auth_tkt cookie format. Apache and nginx support this, for example, and Plone 4 has built-in auth_tkt cookie format support.
- Use a shared ActiveDirectory/LDAP repository to share account id, roles, etc.

Content:

- Use something like [ore.contentmirror](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ore.contentmirror) to export content from Plone to a database and render through the ASP.NET application
- Use a Plone view to render only what you want and either scrape this into the ASP.NET application or use an `<iframe />` to render it.
- Use Diazo (XDV) at the web server level to merge the two applications visually - this will work best if entire areas of the site are to be served by Plone rather than just pulling in some content here and there.

Comment: In the second bullet under "Content": "or use an to render it"?  "An" what, please?

Comment: @Auspex An iframe. Was visible in the post source but got lost in the rendering. Fixed now.