# How to wrap Plone authentication around a third-party servlet?

Tags: python, authentication, nginx, plone

We're using Plone to serve up some third-party middle-ware.

Unfortunately the middle-ware has a particular servlet that gets invoked from a Java applet and doesn't do any kind of authentication. I would like to firewall this off and somehow wrap authentication around it, preferably using the existing session that users will have on Plone.

My first idea was to configure nginx (which we're using as the reverse proxy) to check the cookie and only proxy if the user has a valid session (along the lines of [this example](https://gist.github.com/2031652)). However, how to check the session ID against Plone, since it's all stored in the Zope database?

Alternatively we could have a Plone python script that basically passes everything along to the back-end after authenticating, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions? Or alternative ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Plone uses a `auth_tkt` session cookie; any system that supports such session cookies *and* that is configured with the same secret as Plone can validate the cookies.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate a nginx implementation of auth_tkt; the standard originates with the Apache [`mod_auth_tkt` module](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/), so if Apache is an option you could use that. See [Plone & CGI single-sign-on using mod_auth_tkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215004/plone-cgi-single-sign-on-using-mod-auth-tkt) for details on how to configure such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own Plone custom add-on which provides a browser view doing the session check for you inside Plone process. How to involve this from Nginx is a mystery for me.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/browserviews.html

Checking if the authentication credentials are valid

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions/login.html?highlight=login#extracting-credentials

More about Plone authentication and cookies

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions/cookies.html?highlight=cookies#default-plone-cookies

Comment: Authenticating from a script seems pretty straightforward, but invoking it as a condition from nginx is something I can't figure out. There seems to be a `http_auth` directive for IMAP/POP proxying; would be nice if there was one for HTTP proxy. Maybe I could try the Embedded Perl module, but it looks a bit too experimental. Any suggestions how to go about the other approach: authenticating with a script and passing data through to the webapp?